# Error while unwrapping an Optional value after testing it in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, optional-values

I have a strange error this morning running my code.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is my simple object:

```
class FQ {

    var rating: Float?
    var phone: String?

    init(rating: Float?, phone: String?)
    {
        self.rating = rating
        self.phone = phone
    }
}
```

But I'm testing for nil value in my if statement (`FQ.match() -> FQ?`):

```
let fq: FQ? = FQ.match(self.place!.name, location: self.place!.location)

if fq != nil && fq!.phone != nil {
    self.phone.text = fq!.phone
} else {
    self.phone.text = ""
}
```

But debugging it:

> Printing description of fq: (project.FQ?) fq = Some {
>      rating = 6.0999999
>      phone = "+33 1 53 10 87 19"
>   }

The value is not nil.
The debugger is failing when setting the label value with the phone number.

I thought I understood Optional but it looks like I didn't. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a misleading error message.

My outlet was declared correctly in my view but somehow the linkage between the UI and the Controller disappeared. I think it happened after a merge in Git.

I just had to link the label back to the view selecting my phone outlet variable and everything is now working fine.

Thanks guys, 
Maxime

Answer (score 3):

If you say that `fq` is not nil, then there's only one place where the exception can be generated:

```
self.phone.text = fq!.phone
```

Is `self.phone` a `UILabel` (or similar)? If yes, I presume it's an implicitly unwrapped

```
@IBOutlet var phone: UILabel!
```

Are you sure it is not nil?

Comment: I thought they finally converted all of the implicitly unwrapped stuff in the Objc APIs? But this is the likely answer if not the latest version of Swift.

Comment: I found the issue. My UIlabel was well declared but the outlet link disappeared during a merge I guess. I had to link my label to my controller and now it's working fine. The error message is a bit confusing and misleading.

Comment: @AlvinThompson: UI components in custom view controllers, views etc. are always (implicitly unwrapped) optionals, because the are not created at instantiation time, and I don't think that is gonna change.

Comment: @maxwell2022: generally speaking compilation messages are often cryptic and misleading - but in this case it was clear it was about an unwrapped optional being nil. A missing outlet link can be the cause.

Comment: @Antonio: I see! I haven't gotten that far yet.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `fq.phone` is also an optional, so you can't assign it to `self.phone.text` (I assume not an optional) without unwrapping it first. Try:

```
self.phone.text = fq!.phone!
```